# Can floating point computation be used in any reliable function notably containers and algorithms?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, predicate, fma

In C and C++ floating point computations are non deterministic by default as not even the true datatype is chosen by user, as for any intermediate computation of a FP subexpression, **the compiler can choose to represent a value with higher precision (that is as another *real* datatype)**.

[Some compilers (GCC) were known to do that for any automatic variable, not just the (anonymous) intermediate result of a subexpression.]

The compiler can do that for a few computations, in some functions; it can do it in some cases and not other for exactly the same subexpression.

It can even inline a function and use a different precision each time a function is called in the source code. **It means that any inlinable function can have its semantics call dependent**; only separately compiled, ABI-called functions (those functions that are called according to conventions described by the ABI and which act essentially as a black box) have the absolute guarantee of having only one floating point behavior, fixed during *separate* compilation (that means that no global optimization occurs).

[Note that this is similar to how string literals are defined: any two computation of the same string literal in the source code can refer to the same or different character arrays.]

That means that even for a purely applicative functions the fundamental equality `f(x) == f(x)` is only guaranteed if floating point operations (and string literals) are *not* used (or that the address of a string literal is only used to access its elements).

So floating point operations have **non deterministic semantics with an arbitrary choice made by the compiler for each and every FP operations** (which seems a lot more perverse that the very small issue of letting the compiler choose which subexpression A or B to compute first in `A+B`).

It seems that function that does any computation with intermediate floating point values cannot be used in any STL container or algorithm that expects a functor *satisfying axioms*, such that

- sorted containers: `set`, `map`, `multiset`, `multimap`
- hashed containers
- sorting algorithms: `sort`, `stable_sort`
- algorithm operating on sorted ranges: `lower_bound`, `set_union`, `set_intersection`...

**as all binary predicates and hash functions must be deterministic before axioms can even be conceived**, that they must be is purely applicative, mathematical function with a defined value of all possible inputs, which is never the case with C++ non-deterministic floating point intermediate values?

In other words, are floating point operations by default almost unusable based on the standard alone, and only usable using in real world implementations that have some (vague) implicit guarantees of determinism?

Comment: You have a weird definition of "deterministic". Given the same code, a given compiler MUST always generate equivalent results under the as-if rule (barring UB being present). Predictability is not the same thing as reproducibility.

Comment: No it does **not** as I explained: "_the compiler can choose to represent a value with higher precision_"

Comment: That makes the compiler **unpredictable**, not **non-deterministic**.

Comment: Can you explain the difference with an example?

Comment: @curiousguy Things can be unpredictable and deterministic, but they can't be non-deterministic and predictable. Before you compile your program, you don't know what the compiler is going to make (it's unpredictable) but it's output is not influenced by randomness (it's deterministic).

Comment: Modern compilers don’t do that. They compile floating point math into either SSE (single precision) or SSE2 (double precision) instructions. That higher-precision thing was the case for legacy x87 FPU that still present in x86 CPUs but not used by modern software. And ARM never had 80-bit stack-based FPU, the instructions there operate on either 32- or 64-bit floats depending on the instruction, just like SSE on PCs.

Comment: @Soonts 1) So higher precision registers was only an issue on Intel? 2) The recommandation to avoid exact equality testing that we see everywhere is obsolete now?

Comment: @molbdnilo What do you mean "not influenced by randomness"? Can you give a procedure that would determine that? Why can't the compiler randomize results? What disallow it?

Comment: @curiousguy 1. Intel, AMD, VIA, etc., with x87 FPU from 1980. Nowdays, the only place with higher precision is intermediate data in FMA instructions, not accessible whatsoever. 2. Sometimes you may use exact equality test if you calculate a value by exactly same code, compile with `/fp:precise` if it’s VC++, control for rounding modes in MXCSR register, and you use exactly equal inputs. If you calculate value by slightly different code, you will still get different results, e.g. `(a+b)*c` and `a*c+b*c` will be different.

Comment: @Soonts So compilers can now guarantee that additional precision will not come into play and break otherwise correct programs? Why won't the std committee also provide that extremely basic guarantee?

Comment: @curiousguy They don’t guarantee that, but that’s how they work in practice. Also they still change the exact result if you play with the options, e.g. they may or may not emit FMA instructions. Also MXCSR register changes exact result too, and this one may get changed in runtime without recompilation. As for the C standard, I don’t think they will update. I only code for modern x86 and ARM but there’re other people out there coding C for all sort of weird target platforms.

Comment: @Soonts The issue isn't so much changing behavior w/o recompilation but the idea that the exact same function call can exhibit essentially infinitely many behaviors during the same run of a program. It's crazy on its face.

Comment: @curiousguy Computers don’t do that, and they didn’t even with x87. With x87, you’re guaranteed to get no more than 288 cases, controlled by bits in x87 control register: 3 precisions * 2 denormal values * 6 interrupt masks * 2 infinity modes * 4 rounding modes. With modern compilers it’s just 8, 4 rounding modes * 2 flush to zero modes, controlled by MXCSR bits.

Comment: I was not accusing the CPU of doing that. My whole point here is that **compilers can output many different asm sequences for similar code**; with complex functions, the number of different compilations is only bounded by compiler limits. The various modes set in the MXCSR register had some more variations, but at least the MXCSR value can be set and verified.

Comment: [Boost's got you covered.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html)

Comment: The trick with floating point numbers is to treat them less as mathematical symbols, and more as traditional scientific notation numbers: as estimates of real numbers with some tolerance.

Comment: @Frank Which compiler compiles in a deterministic way such as the same source code always produce the same asm/binary?

Comment: @hegel5000 An estimate of which real number?

Comment: @Soonts "_Nowdays, the only place with higher precision is intermediate data in FMA instructions, not accessible whatsoever._" What do you mean by "not accessible"?

Comment: @curiousguy Actual real numbers, measured from actual real life.

Comment: @hegel5000 Program inputs can be physical measures, but all the other floating point values are the results of computations, not of physical things.

Comment: @curiousguy Yes, and the errors compound during computation.  [There are rules for that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_arithmetic).  If you want symbols representing real values, rather than finite-precision estimates, maybe you want something like Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: @hegel5000 I want no such thing, only reliable, predictable, repeatable fp computations.

Comment: @curiousguy I don't think that that's what floating point is actually for.

Comment: @hegel5000 What is fp for?

Comment: @curiousguy As I said before: representing traditional scientific notation numbers, thus estimating real numbers within some tolerance.

Comment: @hegel5000 I get that. But shouldn't fp arithmetic be repeatable and deterministic like computations with normal data types?

Comment: @curiousguy A value of an integer type (e.g. a string) represents precisely one integer value, and with 100% accuracy.  Meanwhile, a single non-NaN FP value represents an infinite set of real numbers (and of course, most reals require infinite data to precisely represent).  So they're fundamentally different beasts.

Comment: @hegel5000 The value of a fp object corresponds to exactly one real number. And the value of an integer can be taken as the close approximation: my watch gives the integral number of seconds for the time, but that doesn't mean that the time is h:m:s exactly to the millisecond.

Comment: @curiousguy If a floating point value is interpreted as representing precisely one real number, then the set of FP numbers would represent an infinitesimally small subset of the reals within a given interval.  While this interpretation is valid, it isn't really that practical.  I think a lot of this is that you just need to get into the practical, heavy-duty usage of FP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204021/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-hegel5000).

Comment: @curiousguy The double versions of these instructions use higher-precision floats internally (maybe 128 bit, I don’t know) for intermediate results. Not accessible because the value these FMA instructions return on output is 64-bit floats, just like the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler is allowed to use higher precision operations and temporary values when evaluating floating-point arithmetic expressions. So if you do `a1 = b+c; a2 = b+c;`, then yes, it's possible for `a1` and `a2` to not be equal to each other (due to double rounding).

That really doesn't matter to the algorithms and containers you mentioned, though; those don't do any arithmetic on their values. The "axioms" that those rely on are those of ordering relationships at most.

The worst you could say is that if you'd previously stored `b+c` in, say, a `set`, doing `mySet.find(b+c)` might fail. So yeah, don't do that. But that's something you don't generally do anyway, the rounding error produced by floating-point arithmetic already making it rare to expect exact equality from derived quantities.

About the only time that you do start having to worry about extended precision is when you're calculating theoretical FP error bounds on a sequence of operations. When you're doing that, you'll know what to look for. Until then, this problem is not a problem.

Comment: 1) Containers don't do any operations obviously because they are valid for any mathematical object types (integers, pointers, strings...), so no specific operation can be assumed to exist. So of course containers don't do math operations! 2) Axioms exist for any keyed container: they need an invariant on keys. 3) What happens when the user tries to insert a value close but not equal to an existing value is fully specified and not a problem with the container specification, **as long as the value is rounded to the container key type before being compared**.

Comment: 4) "_So yeah, don't do that_" Then please explain how you can possibly never do that very basic thing. Don't do that seems to be the mantra of FP programming but there is no hint that this is even possible.

Comment: It sounds like you're overestimating the compiler's latitude to not care about floating point equality. `mySet.insert(b+c); mySet.find(b+c)` is not guaranteed to work, but `float a = b+c; mySet.insert(a); mySet.find(a)` *is* guaranteed to work. The *only* time the compiler is allowed to use excess precision is when evaluating an arithmetic expression.

Comment: Incidentally, I can't really think of any non-contrived situations where you'd want to key a container on a floating point type. They're really more a value sort of thing. If you have a concrete example of something you'd like to do but can't because of floating point error, you should definitely ask that as a new question. It might be more productive.

Comment: "_you're overestimating_" Do you disagree with the statement that many GCC versions gave zero importance to the declared type of automatic variables, w/o causing a major scandal among users? IOW GCC treated declared local variables (whose address is not taken) and temporary values exactly the same as during the intermediate state of the compilation they are the same thing. (Which makes sense intuitively for normal scalar values.)

Comment: You can't think of any case where you would need to sort FP values, really? Or keep FP values sorted?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the GCC bug you're describing, but I know for a fact that GCC has had bugs, so I don't see any reason to disbelieve you. :-) As for sorting, that's a great example of something that *is* guaranteed to work.

Comment: (BTW, it really sounds from your tone that you're angry about something, but for the life of me I can't think what. Keep it friendly. We're all here to help each other.)

Comment: Breaking axioms and the ability to even have predicates that are well defined as true or false in the name of optimization, w/o anyone caring, doesn't make you agree at the ppl doing the breakage? GCC had this behavior by deep design; the entire compiler was written to behave that way. It was bug like it's bug that cleartext HTTP can be spied on.

Comment: @Sneftel “I can't really think of any non-contrived situations where you'd want to key a container on a floating point type” std::set and map are red black trees, keys are sorted. Sometimes it makes sense to use map<float,Value> then upper_bound / lower_bound to query values in interval.

Comment: @Soonts That's a great point. I would argue that in that instance nothing's being exactly *keyed* on the floats, though -- you're not using them to identify elements, only to organize them.